# A generating function that produces $\{n^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I am trying to find a generating function that produces the sequence
$$ 1, 2^2, 3^3, 4^4, 5^5,\cdots,n^n $$
so that
$$ F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^n\frac{x^n}{n!} $$
Does anyone know of such a generating function?  I have been reading the book *generatingfunctionology* but I cannot find such a function or how to derive such a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a generating function

> $$ F(x)=1+xW'_0(-x) .$$

where $W(x)$ is the [Lambert $W$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Here are few terms of the series of $F(x)$

> $$ 1+xW'_0(-x) = 1+x+2\,{x}^{2}+{\frac {9}{2}}{x}^{3}+{\frac {32}{3}}{x}^{4}+{\frac {
> 625}{24}}{x}^{5}+O( {x}^{6}),
>  $$

**Note:** For the proof, just use the power series representation

> $$  W_0 (x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}\ x^n . $$

Comment: I'm just curious; how did you arrive to this conclusion?

Comment: So your result shows that F(x) cannot have a closed-form solution?

Comment: @anthonybell: in fact this is a closed form in terms of a well known special function.